# I can't find VSCode in unity external script editor browser

Tags: unity, scripts, visual-studio-code

I can't find VSCode in unity external script editor browser. Everyone said that it is in usr/bin/code but in when I try to add new script editor i can't find it there. But when I try to find it in file explorer I can find it.
Please help.
Thank you.